# Appcelerator Titanium Studio won't run iOS simulator or allow me to select iOS as target OS

Tags: javascript, ios, ios5, mobile, titanium

I am having trouble developing for iOS with Titanium Studio.  (I am working on a mac running snowleopard.)  I tried to follow this tutorial (https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Quick+Start#QuickStart-HelloWorld%21) and I can get to this stage:
[image]
But under "deployment targets" iPad, iPhone, Andriod, and Blackberry are grayed out and my only option is Mobile Web.  (basically the opposite of the picture).

Then when I go to run my app as instructed (see image below) my only option is "Mobile Web Preview In Browser", which opens firefox, or "run configurations" where iOS is still unavailable.

[image]

On my titanium dashboard, there are icons for iOS and Android which have question marks on top of them.  when I click on iOS, it says that it can't find an iOS SDK and prompts me to download Xcode from the app store.  However, when i go to do this, I am unable because my system is too old for the new Xcode.

Also, if it turns out that the iOS simulator simply can't work on my machine, i still cant figure out how to export my project as a mobile app. (lol)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify where the iOS SDK is located on your machine in order for Titanium Studio to give you the option to deploy to an iOS device. The XCode versioning can understandably get confusing and frustrating, but I think it's time for you to update your Mac to Lion and go with the latest versions of XCode, the Titanium SDK, and Titanium Studio for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

if you open up the dashboard page in the Titanium Studio IDE there is a configuration panel that will assist with configuring IOS SDK and provide instructions on how to tell TiStudio where to find it[image]